# Why is modularity a good idea?

Tags: architecture, single-responsibility, modularization

I have a programmer on my team who wants to take all the control flow logic for handling events sent by any module and put it all in a single file, because they think it will make an already-complex system easier to maintain and grow. How can I convince them that this is a bad idea?

Sources to reading material are welcome, as well as general arguments. Arguments for the idea are also welcome.*

Here's what I've got so far:

- The single file will become a merge nightmare, since adding any module will require adding logic to the central controller. If two engineers add two different features, one will have to resolve the conflicts in the central file.
- The central controller file will get excessively long, growing at least linearly with the number of modules, if not N<sup>2</sup> with the with the number of interactions between different modules.
- Any message handling logic that accesses internal state for a given module will either need to be wrapped in a function (this is not necessarily bad), or have its module expose that state (this is bad).
- The central controller will be highly coupled—since it will have a dependency on every other module in the system—and have very little cohesion, with the blocks of logic only related because they're caused by any two modules interacting together.
- The dependencies between different modules will not be explicit, since a single controller will be responsible for handling those interactions.
- Writing unit tests for each module, or integration tests between two modules will be impossible without pulling in every other module via the central controller. The central controller itself will be pretty much untestable, outside of end-to-end testing.

* Implementing a state machine to control the flow of a system is not necessarily a bad idea, but different parts of the program still need to be modularized and not have to care about states or state transitions that don't matter to them.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I convince them that this is a bad idea?

It might not be a bad idea.

I've seen not a few systems where each event got its own tiny handler class, and the handlers were discovered and dependency injected at runtime leading to a fairly huge fragile mess.

Without knowing what you need to do, and what you might need to eventually do, it's hard to say for sure. But it probably is a bad idea.

On to your points, somewhat as a devil's advocate (since your programmer will likely have similar arguments if they want to put it all together).

> The single file will become a merge nightmare, since adding any module will require adding logic to the central controller. If two engineers add two different features, one will have to resolve the conflicts in the central file.

Enh, this is probably overblown. The different conditions will be in their own blocks, limiting the conflict area. At least Visual Studio can automerge those sorts of conflicts well these days. I can't speak to other IDEs.

> The central controller file will get excessively long, growing at least linearly with the number of modules, if not N2 with the with the number of interactions between different modules.

So what? Splitting the code into different classes will be at least that long, since you have the added overhead of all the class declaration ceremony. You're still doing the same work, so it's going to be the same length code (everything else being equal).

> The central controller will be highly coupled—since it will have a dependency on every other module in the system—and have very little cohesion, with the blocks of logic only related because they're caused by any two modules interacting together.

So what? Even with a highly decoupled set of event handlers, *something* needs to know what they all are and how to tie them together - and that something is going to have just as many coupling points as the one big handler does. If anything, by explicitly stating the dependencies in one place, you can more easily see what they are and break them apart.

> The dependencies between different modules will not be explicit, since a single controller will be responsible for handling those interactions.

Eh? In the normal decoupled version of this I've seen, an Inversion of Control container promptly obfuscates the concrete dependencies. I expect the interactions in the one big controller will be explicitly in code rather implicitly in convention or explicitly in some config file hidden away somewhere.

> Writing unit tests for each module, or integration tests between two modules will be impossible without pulling in every other module via the central controller. The central controller itself will be pretty much untestable, outside of end-to-end testing.

Not always. If the big handler doesn't use all of the modules to handle the event you're testing, you don't need to mock all of the modules since they would be unused. It would take some care to do right, and it may be impossible given your requirements, but not a surefire argument.

Some other common arguments:

> If someone changes one module, it causes our consumer to update all of them!

Depending on your requirements, they might need to do that anyways (because you version the entire system, because the dependencies are so pervasive that the change would cascade).

> If it's in the big controller, we can't reuse/compose modules!

Sure, but almost every system I've seen like this couldn't do that anyways. The dependencies were too pervasive either between the modules or on cross cutting concerns (logging, security, data access, etc).

But the big thing to note is that all of my counter arguments are the sort of "it would be effectively equivalent" to the modular code. Why go through all the work of shuffling things around if it won't provide a clear benefit?

And largely, the complaints against the one big class are impacts of violating the Single Responsibility Principle. It is a well known guideline that has stood against criticism and the rigors of practical OO design for years. There is literally decades of evidence from programmers better than you, I or your coworker that says making a class with multiple responsibilities will lead to pain and badness.

Answer (score 2):

There is an anti-pattern - [God Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Just like you stated, God Objects:

- are hard to maintain
- usually violate one or many [SOLID principles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))
- impossible to understand for new developers
- hard to locate functionality in for new developers
- do not describe system at first glance at file structure
- etc.

Having module controller is quite OK actually, something should have knowledge of all the modules, however, the only responsibility of such a class should be providing modules for its users.

Anything specific to  a module should be inside the module and have nothing to do with this class.

Common practice is to write such a class once and provide a list file(xml, json, etc...) with modules. As modules are added to the system, the main Module Controller doesn't change, because it was decoupled enough from the modules in the first place.

Comment: But why is a God Object a bad idea? Simply giving it an anti-pattern name won't convince anyone :)

Comment: Edited. =======